# Best way to define constants in my Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a preferred way to define my constants that I will use in my theme?

1- Can I Define it as a method in my class?

```
<?php MyClass::templatename(); ?>
```

2- Or using define?

```
<?php define( 'TEMPLATE_NAME', 'mytheme' ); ?>
```

Comment: I normally use `define` and I always check if the constant exists already in order to avoid conflict, here is the syntax: `defined('TEMPLATE_NAME) or define('TEMPLATE_NAME', 'mytheme');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a whole function for a single static value is not very efficient. Because of that, I would go with the `define` method. You could define this constant in a `constant.php` file, which would be imported by your theme's `function.php`.

You could also define a class constant, this could be interessting if your are defining a non-uniquely named constant, and you think this constant might leak somewhere else in the code. ( A good example would be a constant named `DEBUG`, because a similar constant is already defined and use elsewhere. )

You can define a class variable using the keyword `const`.

```
class MyClass {
    const TEMPLATE_NAME = 'some value';
}

// use it as such
echo MyClass::TEMPLATE_NAME;
```

Comment: Thanks, now I make a function for each post meta field I need, check if has value, add html wrapper and translate or add text to it instead of making this in template file. is this not a good way? and what's your advice for doing that?